# How can I print first negative number after a positive number in a list?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I want to print first negative number after a positive number in a python list. But I am unable to do this

`lst = [2,4,-4,-5,-7,2,3,5,6,-9,-4,-6,3,45,6,-67,-45,-56]`

In this list I want to print only -4,-9,-67

Comment: What about input `[1, 0, -1]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
lst = [2, 4, -4, -5, -7, 2, 3, 5, 6, -9, -4, -6, 3, 45, 6, -67, -45, -56]

out = [b for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]) if a > 0 and b < 0]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[-4, -9, -67]
```

Comment: Is that memory optimal tho?

Comment: @sudden_appearance If memory is a concern you can use [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise)

Comment: I mean, your answer can be modified to `out = [lst[i + 1] for i in range(len(lst) - 1) if lst[i] > 0 and lst[i + 1] < 0]` which does absolutely the same thing and looks almost the same, but memory efficient)

Comment: @sudden_appearance You can write it as an answer, I'll upvote it. (Me personally I avoid to manually index a list - only if absolutely necessary)

Answer (score 2):

With Python 3.10+:

```
from itertools import pairwise

for a, b in pairwise(lst):
    if a > 0 > b:
        print(b)
```

Without:

```
a = 0
for b in lst:
    if a > 0 > b:
        print(b)
    a = b
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this:

```
for c, item in enumerate(lst): # go through all of the items and their indexs
    if item < 0 and c > 0 and lst[c - 1] >= 0: # check if the previous item is positive and the current number is negative
        print(item) # print the current item
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit modified answer of @Andrej Kesely, without producing sliced list (by means of using indexes instead) you can achieve same result

```
out = [lst[i + 1] for i in range(len(lst) - 1) if lst[i] > 0 and lst[i + 1] < 0]

# [-4, -9, -67]
```

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: You haven't specified what should be the right approach to a `0` in the list, that could slightly change the answer.

The cleanest way is probably:

```
[b for a,b in zip(lst, lst[1:]) if a > 0 > b]
```

(But it's not very efficient for large lists, because it copies the list)

A more efficient way is probably:

```
[lst[i] for i in range(1, len(lst)) if lst[i - 1] > 0 > lst[i]]
```

(But it's less elegant)

You could always use iterators `(...)` instead of list comprehensions `[...]` if you need more memory efficiency as well.